# What value is returned by "==" operator?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
    int a, b, val;
    
    a = 5;
    b = 6;
    
    val = a == b;
    
    printf("The value is::: %d", val);
    
    getch();
}
```

I have a basic c-program above. Here the value of variable "val" will be 0 because a is not equals to b and the output is printed as "The value is::: 0".

My question is whether I can use this syntax in c-programming or not? Actually my teacher is arguing that the value won't be 0 or 1. I displayed him the output and now he is saying that I cannot use this in c-programming. Is this true ?

He says that a==b won't give 0 or 1 based on the values of a and b.

Comment: It is either `1` if `a` is equal to `b`, or `0` otherwise. (don't use `getch()`, the `conio.h` header is an arcane DOS header and 100% non-portable, simply use `getchar()` to hold the terminal open on windows)

Comment: Get a new teacher... Also Unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a standards conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`).  See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: As a follow up, the applicable section of the [C11 Standard - 6.5.9 Equality operators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9p3) reads "Each of the operators [`==` or `!=`] yields `1` if the specified relation is *true* and `0` if it is *false*. The result has type `int`. For any pair of operands, exactly one of the relations is true." (emphasis added)

Comment: Maybe your teacher doesn't know about [operator precedence rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) in C++. The expression `val = a == b` can be written equivalently as `val = (a == b)` for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above by David C. Raskin, the standard clearly says that result of the `==` is `int` with value either 0 or 1. So the code is pretty legitimate and produces expected resulting value, and so your teacher seems to be wrong. On the other hand, if the entire purpose of that code is to assign initial zero value to the variable, it is not best code, and in this sense your teacher is right. Good code should be readable and clearly express what you want to do, and in such case, it is just better to have `val=0`.